# Projecting onto the Kronecker factor

Tags: ergodic-theory

I'm new here, nice to meet you all. I'm doing a PHD in mathematics, and I need your help.
My question is this:
Given a measure-preserving system X, And a bounded function f\in\L^\infty(X), the projection of f on the invariant factor of the system is given by
E_n foT^n.
From here, of course, we can also derive the L^2 norm of the projection.

What similar things can we say about the projection on the Kronecker factor?
I know that the Kronecker factor is related to the second Gowers-Host-kra seminorm, and to the multiple ergodic average E_n (foT^n)(goT^2n). Do any of those yield a formula to compute the prjection itself, or at least its' L^2(X) norm?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).